# Captura de Tela (Mapa)

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

Galera coloquei um mapa no meu site e quero fazer um botão que gera uma imagem png quando clicado nele, utilizei o html2Canvas porém quando clico ele não consegue salvar a imagem do mapa.

Código utilizado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Html2 Canvas</title>

    <!-- Html2Canvas -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasmin.js"></script>

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.tecnologicbrasil.com.br/leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <script src="http://www.tecnologicbrasil.com.br/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="prints();">Click para dar print</button>

     <div id="mapa" style="position: absolute; top: 25%; left: 25%; margin: 0; width: 50%; height: 50%;">
    </div>

    <div id="colamapa"style=" margin: 0; width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: red">as</div>

      <script id="teste" type="text/javascript">
                var map = L.map('mapa').setView([-3.130409,-60.023426], 12);
                L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'Mapas &copy; OpenCycleMap, Dados do Mapa &copy; contribuidores do OpenStreetMap'}).addTo(map);
      </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function prints(){ 
            html2canvas(document.querySelector("#mapa")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

O site de onde tiro js do html2canvas é este:

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Existem [alguns plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport) para o Leaflet.js que fazerm o que tu quer.

Comment: Tentei utilizar o plugin deles mas não está pegando, só pega com aquele mapa que está no site deles, tentei adicionar a função aos meus mapas mas não funcionou. e quero que está função consiga capturar não só de um mapa mas de vários. mas muito obrigado pela sugestão da biblioteca leaflet.

Comment: você pode incluir direto no nas tags meta do html link direto do js
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js

Comment: há plugins para iso, como este: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image mas pode nao funcionar, pode tentar